# Is it possible to render one half of a scene by OpenGL and other half by DirectX

Tags: opengl, directx

My straight answer would be NO. But I am curious how they created this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC3JGG6xHN8

Comment: Why not? Based on what logic?

Answer (score 1):

They used video editing software. They recorded two nearly deterministic run-throughs of their engine and spliced them together.

As for the question posed by your title, not within the same window. It may be possible within the same application from two windows, but you'd be better off with two separate applications.

Comment: Hmm, sounds more like a comment. The actual question is much more interesting (even if the one you answered is the only one from the question body).

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible, especially with vendor specific extensions like [NV_DX_interop](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop.txt). Impractical, yes very but even without extensions you could conceivably just copy the frame-buffer to memory at great performance-loss but not impossible.

Comment: @PeterT: As I said, "not within the same *window*". That doesn't preclude an application from creating a GL window and a D3D window, as I stated.

Comment: *"As for the question posed by your title, not within the same window."* - Well not as easy, yet you may render into offscreen buffers and compose the result together (but Ok, that's maybe not what the OP was looking for either). Or maybe with the NV_dx_interop extension (or however that's called)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I did this as an experiment for a graduate course; I implemented half of a deferred shading graphics engine in OpenGL and the other half in D3D10. You can share surfaces between OpenGL and D3D contexts using the appropriate vendor extensions.

Does it have any practical applications? Not many that I can think of. I just wanted to prove that it could be done :)

I digress, however. That video is just a side-by-side of two separately recorded videos of the Haven benchmark running in the two different APIs.

Answer (score 1):

> My straight answer would be NO.

My straight answer would be "probably yes, but you definitely don't want to do that."

> But I am curious how they created this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC3JGG6xHN8

They prerendered the video, and simply combined it via video editor. Because camera has fixed path, that can be done easily.

Anyway, you could render both (DirectX/OpenGL) scenes onto offscreen buffers, and then combine them using either api to render final result. You would read data from render buffer in one api and transfer it into renderable buffer used in another api. The dumbest way to do it will be through system memory (which will be VERY slow), but it is possible that some vendors (nvidia, in particular) provide extensions for this scenario.

On windows platform you could also place two child windows/panels side-by-side on the main windows (so you'll get the same effect as in that youtube video), and create OpenGL context for one of them, and DirectX device for another. Unless there's some restriction I'm not aware of, that should work, because in order to render 3d graphics, you need window with a handle (HWND). However, both windows will be completely independent of each other and will not share resources, so you'll need 2x more memory for textures alone to run them both.

Comment: You don't have to _transfer_ data between APIs if you use NV_dx_interop/2. You're given a handle to a D3D9/10/11 surface that can be used directly as a texture attachment in OpenGL without any copying. The trick here is that you have to be running a version of Windows that uses the WDDM driver model (Vista+).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: "some vendors (nvidia, in particular) provide extensions for this scenario." I never used this extension, so I didn't write about it. NVidia is not the only GPU manufacturer, by the way. Methods I mentioned should work pretty much everywhere (it'll be slow and inefficient, though).

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were implying that NV had an extension that allowed you to copy data through system memory. You don't even need an extension for that :P